# In Azure, how to deploy to production slot using Visual Studio?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azureportal

I'm trying to learn how to deploy Web Application to Azure using Visual Studio 2015. I could successfully deploy a simple Web Application (without creating any slot). I moved to the ARM portal and found that there isn't any slot. However, when I try to swap, I can see "production" as an option in the source & destination drop down lists.

I created another slot and then I tried to publish the Web Application again, but I could only see one slot, which is the newly created slot (please see the screen shot)

[image]

I'm a bit confused. According to my understanding, there should be a default slot which I can deploy specifically to it and then swap to/from it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the "TestWithDB20170822062605" application is your default application. You could directly select this web app. If you publish the application to this. It will be regard as production app.

If select the TestWithDBSlot2, it will publish the application to your newly created slot.

[image]

---

Firstly, if you select the "TestWithDB20170822062605" application, VS will publish the application to the TestWithDB20170822062605.azurewebsites.net.

This is according to the url not the slot or something else.

But if you swap the web app.

It will like this

TestWithDB20170822062605.azurewebsites.net -------->  TestWithDBSlot2

TestWithDBSlot2.azurewebsites.net  -----------> Production

So you will find you publish the application to the slot TestWithDBSlot2, but the url is still TestWithDB20170822062605.azurewebsites.net. This is according to the url not the slot name.

Comment: Sorry... I was mistaken. Actually, when I select "TestWithDB20170822062605", it will always deploy to the slot which is currently active. i.e. if I swap to production and deploy by selecting "TestWithDB20170822062605", it will deploy to production. If I swap to TestWithDBSlot2 and deploy by selecting "TestWithDB20170822062605", it will deploy to TestWithDBSlot2

Comment: In my opinion, this is right. You could see my update answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. However, the original question wasn't answered yet. I need to know how to publish to either of the slot no matter which one of them is currently in use

Comment: The slot is designed for swap your application.  If you still publish to that slot, it doesn't need use slot, we could create a new web app. Normally, we will created a deployment slot and a production web app(default). The default web app(production) is used to host the worked well app. The deployment slot is used to test the new version of the web app. If tested complete, then we use swap to swap the deployment with production. So the production will be the slot, the deployment will be the production. If we want to update a new version. We will still publish to the deployment slot.